# c fuction output array skip chars

Tags: c, arrays, function, output

Hi guys so Im working on my homework and I have problem... i have these two functions :

1)

```
int * input()
{   
int c;
static int val[17];
int count;

count = 0;
while(((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (count != 16)) 
{   
    if(c == '\n')   // riesi \n za na konci echa
    {
        break;
    }
    val[count] = c;
    count++;
}
val[count] = EOF; 
count = 0;

return val;
}
</code>
```

2)

```
<code>int output_none()
{
int *val;
int count;
int pos = 0;
do
{
    val = input();
    printf("%08x ", pos);
    pos = pos + 16;

    count = 0;
    //for(int i = 0; val[i] != EOF; i++)
    while(val[count] != EOF)
    {
        printf("%02x  ", val[count]);
        count++;
        if(count == 8)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    if(count < 16)
    {
        while(count != 16)
        {
            printf("    ");
            count++;
        }
    }

    count = 0;
    printf("|");
    //for(int i = 0; val[i] != EOF; i++)
    while(val[count] != EOF)    
    {
        printf("%c", val[count]);
        count++;
    }
    printf("|\n");


}while(count == 16);
}
</code>
```

my problem is that output of this : **echo "Hello, world! Ahoj svete!" | ./proj1**

should be :
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77  6f 72 6c 64 21 20 41 68  |Hello, world! Ah|
00000010  6f 6a 20 73 76 65 74 65  21 0a                    |oj svete!.      |

but what i got is: 
00000000 48  65  6c  6c  6f  2c  20  77   6f  72  6c  64  21  20  41  68  |Hello, world! Ah|
00000010 6a  20  73  76  65  74  65  21                                   |j svete!|

i dont know why my code is skipping some chars when its going for second round of input... sorry for this horrible written post ... Im writing it trough mobile as my laptop died and Im in train on my way to school. Thanks.

Comment: `while(((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (count != 16))` You first read a char _and then_ check if you were done reading. Thats the wrong order.

Comment: while(count == 16);` shold be `while(count != 16);` is this what you intended?

Comment: Tkausl thank you very much ... its working now.. i have been overlooking it for an hour...